# Why is the dispatcher behaving this way when I pass a parameter?

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

I'm using a DataGridView in WPF.
In the RowEditEnding event, I get the old row (before editing ends) and then call a method through dispatcher to get the new row (after edit)

```
private void myGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView oldRowView = e.Row.Item as DataRowView;
    DataRow oldRow = oldRowView.Row;
    //When I put a breakpoint before the dispatcher is called, oldRow has the old row values. 
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => OnRowEdit(oldRow, e)), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
    //I have now passed the old row to OnRowEdit
}

void OnRowEdit(DataRow oldRow, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
  //Here oldRow has new row values. 
}
```

The item array of the oldRow before I call the method and the array after I have called the method don't match. What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: This probably has something to do with the use of your action delegate and capturing the variable in the method.

Comment: Maybe. Still don't understand why it's happening. For now, I'm using a global variable.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's impossible to know for sure what the issue is in your scenario. There's just not enough context here.

But most likely, you're simply running into a temporal issue. That is, the delegate invoked by `BeginInvoke()` is executed asynchronously, at some indeterminate later time. As it's queued for execution, it's almost certainly going to be executed after the update of the row occurs, hence you see the new values by the time your method is executed.

Possible solutions include:

1. Use the `Invoke()` method instead of `BeginInvoke()`. This is executed synchronously, ensuring the row object hasn't been modified when the `OnRowEdit()` method is called.
2. If all you need is the values from the row, extract those into a temporary object (e.g. a new array) before calling `BeginInvoke()` and pass *that* object instead of the row object itself.
3. Just call `OnRowEdit()` directly. Lacking a complete code example, it's not clear why you're using `BeginInvoke()` at all; typically, user editing actions occur in the dispatcher thread, and so one can access UI objects directly, without the need to call `Invoke()` or `BeginInvoke()`. Note that this is practically the same option as #1…it may be that using `Invoke()` would simply be superfluous.

If none of the above options work for you, please improve the question by including a good code example, explaining why you are using `BeginInvoke()` in the first place, and why none of these suggestions work in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I want the old row values as well as the new row values. I can easily get the new row values in the delegate called by BeginInvoke(). That is the reason I first store the old row values before calling BeginInvoke().  I will try using an array to store the values. Will let you know if it works.

Comment: The code you showed, does not "store the old row values". It simply keeps a reference to the row object. Without a proper code example, I can't say for sure. But I'll bet in your `OnRowEdit()` method, the expression `object.ReferenceEquals(oldRow, ((DataRowView)e.Row.Item).Row)` would return `true`. Why are you even using `BeginInvoke()`? It's at the root of your troubles (not counting the possibility of using a view model to mediate the data changes).

Answer (score 0):

What Peter Duniho said to answer your exact question. But the "correct" way of doing this in my opinion would be to use a ViewModel. You then would have a copy of the "old" and could validate the "new" which would solve your issue (I think?). You'd have much more overall control of what happens and there are many other benefits to MVVM also.